# React router with blog like functionality

Tags: reactjs, react-router, router

I am implementing a blog in my current website.

I have a this as my router

```
<Router history={history}>
  <Switch>
    <Route exact path="/" component={Homepage} />
    <Route exact path="/case-studies" component={CaseStudies} />
    <Route path="/case-studies/:id" component={CaseStudiesSingle} />
    <Route path="/about" component={About} />
    <Route exact path="/blog" component={Blog} />
    <Route path="/blog/:id" component={BlogSingle} />
    <Route path="/contact-us" component={ContactUs} />
    <Route render={ () => <h1>Page not found</h1> } />
  </Switch>
</Router>
```

So everything works by putting "exact" on the "/blog" and "/case-studies" I can then go to the single page. The problem is on my blog I have a "RECENT POSTS" sections but when I am on this page "http://mysite.co.uk/blog/the-city-and-its-architecture" for example I can't go to another blog post like this one "http://mysite.co.uk//blog/photographer-and-designers". I can see the url changing but I can't navigate to another "BlogSingle component because I am already on it. Any suggestion?

Many thanks!

Comment: I am getting 404 when visitting that URLs

Comment: @GonFreecss Can you post the code of component BlogSingle?

Answer (score 0):

```
<Route path="/blog/:id" component={BlogSingle} />
```

For this route, because only one of the params is changing with the route remaining the same you're component will stay mounted. If in `BlogSingle` you have logic to determine what is showing with `componentDidMount` you need to put that logic in `componentDidUpdate` and properly update the component when your params change on the `match` prop that the route passes.